# SIP to SIP Call recording

Tags: android, android-ndk

How can we record SIP to SIP call in android? how to get downlink and uplink access in android using native code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). It is an open source project that has the features you are looking for. Generally it uses a pjsip SIP stack that runs on native code. You can ask question in their mailing list. It is very active.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wrote your own Android NDK SIP stack, recording SIP calls on Android is pretty simple.  Just combine inbound and outbound audio (MUX), then write combined audio to file system or some place you want to save the recorded calls.