# Recording SIP Calls

Tags: android, sip, voip

Is there a way to record SIP calls in Android? I've gone through a similar question i.e. [SIP to SIP Call recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445834/sip-to-sip-call-recording). The answer there directs to a native SIP implementation. What I'm looking for is record incoming/outgoing calls while using standard development API i.e. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html.

Comment: Do you want to record the SIP packets, or the audio packets sent inside the SIP session?

Comment: @Moerwald I need to record the audio packets.

Comment: any luck on this ?